# Swipejs does not animate

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement swipejs. Here are the instructions, https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe, and here is the site that I am trying to use it on, http://bannisterwebdesign.co.uk/testing/.

The slideshow is showing but it's not animating. I've added the following into an external file and done everything else as instructed.

```
window.slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
  startSlide: 1,
  speed: 400,
  auto: 3000,
  continuous: true,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false,
  callback: function(index, elem) {},
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
});
```

Can someone see why it's not animating?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that in you copied the CSS code from example which has:

```
.swipe-wrap > div {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

But you are using `<a>` instead of `<div>` in your test. That's why the slider doesn't work. You should change the CSS to

```
.swipe-wrap > a {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Hope it helps.